# How to make file upload 'Required' in Contact Form 7?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a Contact Form 7 form on my Wordpress website and I have specified that the file upload is mandatory by putting a `*`, however the users are able to submit the form without file upload.

Relevant Contact Form 7 form is given below:

```
<div class="filelink">[file* AddanImage filetypes:gif|png|jpg|jpeg]</div>
```

How do I write the Contact Form 7 code or add a validation perhaps so that the users are not able to submit the form without uploading an image?

Any hints/help/guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you check doc - https://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/

Comment: @MukeshPanchal I have and the code complies with the documentation

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to check if the value of a file is existing.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form'),
      span = document.createElement("span"),
      text = document.createTextNode("Please upload a file: "),
      parent = document.getElementById("file").parentNode,
      file = document.getElementById('file');
      
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  if (file.value === '') {
    e.preventDefault();
    parent.insertBefore(span, file);
    span.appendChild(text);
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload the file">
</form>
```